# How can I scroll anchorPane in JAVAFX?

Tags: javafx

hi i write code like this in Below and how can i add Scroll in my project,**Note **The line shape added in the image is added by code and is not in scene builder space
`package schedul;

```
    import edu.classes.drawInschedulClass;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
    import javafx.scene.text.Text;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    public class scene11 extends Application {
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

    AnchorPane root=FXMLLoader. 
    <AnchorPane>load(getClass().getResource("/schedul/scene1.fxml"));
    Line line=new Line();
    line.setStartX(50);
    line.setStartY(50);
    line.setEndX(800);
    line.setEndY(50);
    root.getChildren().add(text);
    Scene scene=new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }

    }`
```

[How can i add scroll!??? Please Click to show pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhene.jpg)
when i put ScrollPane in myCode,unfortunatly dose not have good performance and ***myscroll dosnt cover all my Line***
this Code is Below

```
   package schedul;

   import java.io.IOException;
   import javafx.application.Application;
   import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
   import javafx.scene.Scene;
   import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
   import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
   import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
   import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
   import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
   import javafx.scene.text.Text;
   import javafx.stage.Stage;
   public class scene11 extends Application {
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

      AnchorPane root=FXMLLoader. 
    <AnchorPane>load(getClass().getResource("/schedul/scene1.fxml"));
    Line line=new Line();
    
    Text text=new Text();
    line.setStartX(50);
    line.setStartY(50);
    line.setEndX(800);
    line.setEndY(50);
    root.getChildren().add(line);
    HBox content = new HBox(root);
    ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane(content);
    scroller.setFitToWidth(true);
     Scene scene= new Scene(new BorderPane(scroller, null, null, null, 
     null));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }

    }
```

I expected the scroll to be created automatically

Comment: Use a [`ScrollPane`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html).

Comment: ok Yes , but How,when i add ScrollPane, it is not full fitWidth

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. By default, if you simply create a `ScrollPane` and set its `content` to the `AnchorPane`, then if the `AnchorPane` ends up taking more space than the viewport of the `ScrollPane` then it will automatically be scrollable. If that's not what's happening for you, please provide a [mre] demonstrating your use of the `ScrollPane`.

Comment: dear i edited my question, i did ScrollPane but unforttunatly dose not have goog performance Please Look in my question Edit above

Comment: ok Dear! sure but please please help me to solve my Problem

Comment: Please create and post a [mre]. Please be sure to read the link and understand exactly what you are being asked to do. In almost every case, you should create a new project entirely from scratch for the purposes of asking your question; you should not be posting code from your actual project here.

Comment: @vpa Why do you need `fitToWidth(true)`? Why not leave that property `false`?

Comment: @James_D,Hello, you are absolutely right, I am Iranian(Persian) and English is not my native language, I am very sorry for this problem. I am using Google translator now to solve this problem, please forgive me for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I took your sample code and removed the irrelevant bits.

All you need to do to make an AnchorPane scrollable is put it in a ScrollPane.  This is demonstrated by the sample below.  The same will work for any other Pane type.

[image: example output]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScrollApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setScene(
                new Scene(
                        new ScrollPane(
                                new AnchorPane(
                                        new Line(50, 50, 800, 50)
                                )
                        )
                )
        );
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

After the application launches, by default, it will size to fit all of the content, so you won't see the scroll bars.  If you make the window smaller horizontally, you will see the horizontal scrollbar, and similarly for the vertical direction.

Comment: oh my god,Thanks, thanks it works goooooooooooooooooodddddddddddddd!!!